# Как вызвать функцию, название которой находится в строке?

Tags: python, функции

Сейчас сделано через словарь
Вызываю ее с помощью `functions['messages']`

```py
functions = {'messages':messages}

async def messages():
    return
```

Но таким способом нельзя передать аргументы, а мне это нужно. Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: `functions['messages']` - это не вызов, а обращение к функции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто - вот так:

```
functions['messages'](arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Comment: `'str' object is not callable` - эта ошибка говорит о недостоверности