# Как вызвать функцию передав название функции как строку в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, varargs

У меня есть функция:

```
async def regedit():
    return 'dino is run!'
```

И есть переменная в которую помещено название функции, типа строки:

```
foo = 'regedit'
```

Моя задача вызвать функцию `regedit()` передав строку или переменную при вызове самой функции, я хотел бы сделать что-то подобное:

```
await foo()
```

Также я должен иметь возможность передавать аргументы функции, пример:

```
foo_name = 'geter'
arg1, arg2 = '1', '2'

async def geter(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1, arg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = asyncio.run(foo_name(arg1, arg2))
    
    prin(result)    # 1, 2
```

Ранее я пытался найти ответы и нашёл один вопрос идентичный моему - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1232486/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5) однако ответ на вопрос вовсе не рабочий и я не знаю даже как его приняли.

P.s - не стоит интересоваться и писать зачем вызывать так функцию и прочее, мне необходим только ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через `globals` получить объект по имени:

```
foo_name = 'geter'
arg1, arg2 = '1', '2'

def geter(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1, arg2

globals()[foo_name](arg1, arg2)
```

Вывод:

```
('1', '2')
```

Comment: А что если необходимая функция расположена в другом файле, я знаю как импортировать файл, но не знаю как в таком случае вызвать функцию, могли бы помочь?

Comment: к тому же у меня асинхронные функции

Comment: Не думаю, что для асинхронных функций код будет отличаться, хотя это надо проверять. А для импортированных тоже надо проверять, но не думаю, что должна быть какая-то разница. Вы пробовали?

Comment: Я пытался разными способами импортировать даже обычную функцию с другого файла - попытки без успешны, возбуждаются разные ошибки.

Comment: `from файл import функция` такое пробовали? должна по идее функция быть видима в этом случае

Comment: да это пробовал, на отлично работает даже с асинхронной функцией, но у меня функций в файле 120 как минимум и мне было бы желательно импортировать просто файл, чтобы каким-то чудным образом обращаться к одной из 120 функций :)

Comment: `from файл import *` тоже должно работать, но там уже могут быть проблемы с пересечением имён в разных библиотеках )

Comment: К счастью мои функции в файле разные по именам, но а куда поставить приставку `await`, чтобы всё нормально работало? Иначе будет ошибка

Comment: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'getContentTypesHandler.<locals>.swith' was never awaited
  handle = self._ready.popleft()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: Только импортируя всё из файла удалось решить проблему, в итоге `await globals()[fooname](arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @MaximChyorny `await getattr(модуль, fooname)(arg1, arg2)`

Answer (score 2):

Решение, которое вы нашли по ссылке вполне рабочее:

```
foo_name = 'geter'
arg1, arg2 = '1', '2'

def geter(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1, arg2

funcs={'geter':geter}
funcs[foo_name](arg1,arg2)
```

вывод:

```
('1', '2')
```

Comment: ладно, так уж и быть, а как это провернуть с асинхронной функцией и к тому же с другого файла python?